# Requisição Ajax não está funcionando, por quê?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Com esse script eu eu consigo mostrar um contador ao lado de `<i class="fas fa-bell mr-3"></i>` quando tem dados no db marcados como `status = unread`, e quando eu clico no icone `<i class="fas fa-bell mr-3"></i>` atualiza determinado row para `status = read`.

Quando eu insiro dados na minha tabela com o status `= unread` o `$countNT` é incrementado, até ai está funcionando perfeitamente e esse `$countNT` é incrementado sem precisar atualiar a página.

Quando eu clico em `<i class="fas fa-bell mr-3"></i>` eu envio um requisição POST com o Ajax para o arquivo `update.php`, e consigo atualizar o row que antes era `status = unread` agora iria ser `status = read` e o `$countNT` zera.

O problema é que a requisição com Ajax para o arquivo `update.php` só está sendo executada uma vez na página, exemplo: se eu atualizei a página há uns 10s atrás, e em seguida chega uma notificação, eu consigo atualizar a tabela em tempo real sem precisar atualizar a página, mas se eu já havia chamado o arquivo `update.php` com o Ajax naquela página e em seguida chega outra notificação, não vai ser possivel atualizar o meu banco de dados, so posso atualizar o banco de dados se eu recarregar a página. Alguem pode me explicar porque?

html:

```
<div>
    <ul class="navbar-nav textoPerfilDesk dropMenuHoverColor">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown pr-2 dropleft navbarItem ">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle-fk" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fas fa-bell mr-3"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-fk py-3" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item dropMNitemNT" href="um-link">
            <span class="d-flex">
                <img class="imgNT" src="img/1.jpg">
                <span class="pl-2 pt-1">
                    titutlo
                </span>
            </span>
            </a>
        </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <span class="text-white divCountNT" id="datacount"></span>
  </div>
```

script:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#datacount").load("select.php");

    setInterval(function(){
    $("#datacount").load('select.php')
    }, 1000);

  });

  $(document).on('click', '.fa-bell', function (){

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "update.php"
    }).done(function() {
      $("#datacount").load("select.php");
    });

  });
</script>
```

select.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'db.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION))session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
}

$status = 'unread';

    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM noti WHERE status = :status AND user_id = :user_id");
    $sql->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->execute();
    $countNT = $sql->rowCount();

    echo $countNT;

    $conn = null;

    ?>
```

update.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'db.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION))session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
}

$status = 'read';
$sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE noti SET status = :status WHERE user_id = :user_id");
$sql->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();
$countNT = $sql->rowCount();

echo $countNT;

$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: Não consegui entender exatamente o que você está tetando fazer, tem como apresentar algum exemplo?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Sabe aquelas notificaçoes do facebook? Quando chega uma notificaçao mostra um numero ao lado de um icone, e quando vc clica no icone o contador some. Como vc pode notar, no meu codigo, quando eu clico no icone eu faço uma requisição Ajax, para executar a query que está no arquivo `update.php`,  e essa requisição não funciona mais de uma vez na página, sendo assim eu estou tendo que atualizar a página.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Não sei se vc ainda não entendeu. Mas basicamente eu quero executar a query que está dentro do arquivo `update.php` quantas vezes forem necessarias, sem ter que atualizar a página.

Comment: aparentemente não tem nada que restrinja o update.php de ser chamado mais de uma vez... Se clicar no sino haverá um post para esse script,  o que eu não vejo é alguma instrução para exibir e esconder o sino. E talvez fosse interessante repensar a sua estratégia... fazer uma requisição por segundo para trazer consultar o `select.php` pode trazer muitos problemas de performance do lado do servidor e do cliente.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo O codigo para esconder o sino é esse: `if($countNT >= 1){ echo $countNT; }` eu não coloquei na pergunta pq n é relevante. O problema de performance eu posso resolver depois, vc tem alguma ideia do pq eu estou tendo que atualizar a página?

Comment: Consegue adicionar seu html todo? não consegui achar o `#datacount`

Comment: @edsonalves Eu uso `echo` para imprimir esse html, e esqueci de colocar o `<span>` que está com o id `#datacount`, desculpe. Já editei o código.

Comment: Para que não haja duvidas, o código na pergunta é todo o código que uso, eu só havia retirado o `if($countNT >= 1){ echo $countNT; }`, que não interfere em nada no erro que descrevi.

Comment: Tb não entendi a questão do botão do sino. Pelo que entendi, você pode clicar a hora que quiser nele que irá chamar o Ajax para atualizar o BD sem precisar atualizar a página. Agora, vc tem um sério problema no código usando setInterval para chamar Ajax. Provavelmente isso está criando um gargalo no servidor. Imagina vc fazer requisições a cada segundo sem esperar que uma tenha terminado e já fazer outra por cima depois de 1 segundo, e ainda fazer outra requisição do Update por cima. A chance de isso dar certo é mínima (pra não dizer nula).

Comment: @Sam Como eu disse, so atualiza o BD uma vez sem atualizar a página. Vc falou que n devo usar o senInterval, talvez seja por isso que estou com esse problema? Se sim. oq vc recomenda?

Comment: @Sam Suspeito que minha explicação na pergunta n foi muito clara. Pq está aparecendo comentarios dizendo que (n entendi direito). Que parte vc n entendeu? Vou tentar editar a pergunta.

Comment: @Sam Pensando bem, agora que eu lembrei de uma coisa, eu estava fazendo uns testes, no momento o meu `senIntervel` é 1000, eu lembrei que quando eu troquei o 1000 por 10000, o banco de dados n atualizava neim mesmo se eu recarregasse a página.